# Power Automate - Slow performance - date formatting from excel , copying to list

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have this workflow where I have two apply to each and many compose fields.

Is there a way to optimize this for faster execution? I am getting an error about slow running.

The excel table has only 1600 rows and I am only using about 5 columns to populate my sharepoint.

flow -

[image]

[image]

[image]

Compose statements are repeatable for date fields,

`items('Apply_to_each')?[concat('Period Planned ', '/', ' Revised Date')]`
`addDays('1899-12-30',int(outputs('Compose')),'yyyy-MM-dd')`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try enabling concurrency control from apply to each action settings? Let me know if it helps to reduce the flow run time.

Comment: Looks to be faster..still running after 1 hour... 1530 records complete.. seems stuck on it lol. Expecting 1675 records roughly.

Comment: it works!! only 1:30 min this time! Flow runs fine and populates everything correctly. But I still get an error `ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.` on compose 2... i wonder why.. could it be because of my pagnation limit?

Comment: Maybe flow expression is not working, correctly either because of one of the inputs (excel column) is blank or is not in proper date/int format as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn ON **Concurrency Control** option from the settings of the apply to each actions to reduce the flow run time.

These settings looks like this:

[image]

You can set the degree of parallelism as per your requirements.